# How to get user value in base.html?

Tags: django

I'd like to work with user data in main base.html which is my main template.

I actually use the login generic view. When I'm logged in on the homepage it gives me user information but in all other pages `user` is blank.

I've read many things about this: `request`, `RequestContext`, I've added `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` to the processors list.

Any idea how to get this variable to show everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

If you're using django 1.4+, you can use, [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) when returning from your views:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
return render(request, 'template.html', ctx)
```

If you're using older django or you don't like the render approach, you would return RequestContext using [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response), like this:

```
def my_view(request):
   ...
return render_to_response('template.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Edit:** sorry, forgot to actually answer question. If you're rendering your templates using one of the above ways and have:

- django.contrib.auth in your INSTALLED_APPS
- auth in midleware
- auth in context_processors
  (take a look at default settings.py file: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py )

Then you can use: {{ user }} and {{ user.is_anonymous }} to figure out what's going on.

Comment: thanks but i'm not sure, it's what i'm waiting for. i think i'll use session to get information, this will simplier than user.

Comment: Ups, expanded with a more complete answer.